# Grails How to save data in a table with belongsTo association?

Tags: grails, grails-orm

I have two model classes: User and Balance.

```
class User {

Balance balance
String name
String role
String password
static constraints = { }
}


class Balance {

double balance
static belongsTo = [user:User]
static constraints = {}
}
```

Every balance belongs to a user. Now, I need to save user and balance details in their respective tables using saveAdd() function.

```
 def saveAdd(){
    def name = params.name
    def password= params.password
    def balance = Double.parseDouble(params.balance)
    def u = new User(name:name,password:password,role:"user", balance: new Balance(balance:balance))
    u.save(flush:true)
}
```

But I get "java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException: null" error.
Is there any mistake in the mapping process? What am I missing?

Comment: That mapping is correct and perists like you expect. With those constraints you wont get it to the database if your params yield `null` values to `name`, `password` or `balance`. You should first try persisting with hard-coded values and then with dynamic data from params. The problems is most likely in the `params`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would reorganize the code so:

```
class User {   
  static hasOne = [ balance:Balance ]
}

class Balance {
  static belongsTo = [user:User]
}
```

then you should have no problems saving the objects in your controller:

```
 def saveAdd(){
    def u = new User(...)
    def b = new Balance(user:u, ...)
    b.save()
    u.save(flush:true)
}
```